# uBlock - rewrite href text

Tags: adblock, ublock-origin, ublock

Lets say I have the following link on some page

```
<a href="https://example.com/string?param1=1&param2=2">Title</a>
```

And using uBlock I'd like to rewrite it to:

```
<a href="https://example.com/string">Title</a>
```

I've found some [Adblock Plus article](https://adblockplus.org/development-builds/rewriting-url-instead-of-blocking) and the [documentation](https://help.eyeo.com/adblockplus/how-to-write-filters#rewrite) which seems like what I need.

I'm not sure if uBlock supports that syntax. I'm trying the following rule:

```
(example.com/string/)(\?.+)$rewrite=$1
```

But `$1` is marked as error by uBlock editor, same as this example from [Adblock Plus article](https://adblockplus.org/development-builds/rewriting-url-instead-of-blocking):

```
/(^https?:\/\/example\.com\/page-123\.php)\?.*/$rewrite=$1
```

This may be a feature of Adblock Plus, but it fails to accept these rules too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was discussed, but declined due to security concerns.
https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uBlock-issues/issues/46

You might wanna have a look at addons that do only this:
https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/requestcontrol/

Comment: Thanks, inside this discussion I found [this](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/adblock-plus-filters-can-be-exploited-to-run-malicious-code/), I think this is the main reason.